# Making DefaultIfEmpty return null

Tags: c#, linq, defaultifempty

I have a class that has 4 fields for nullable doubles:

```
public class myClass
{
    public double? i1;
    public double? i2;
    public double? i3;
    public double? i4;
}
```

And I have 4 lists that may hold various values or be empty, for example:

```
List<double> inputs1 = new List<double> { 1, 2, 3 };
List<double> inputs2 = new List<double> { 4, 5 };
List<double> inputs3 = new List<double> { };
List<double> inputs4 = new List<double> { 8, 9 };
```

Now, I want to create a list of instances of `myClass` that hold all possible combinations of these values. To avoid complex foreach loop (in full application there are many more lists and fields in `myClass`), I am using this LINQ expression:

```
List<myClass> myObjects = (
    from double? input1 in inputs1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from double? input2 in inputs2.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from double? input3 in inputs3.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from double? input4 in inputs4.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new myClass()
    {
       i1 = input1,
       i2 = input2,
       i3 = input3,
       i4 = input4
    }
).ToList();
```

The intent behind `DefaultIfEmpty()` is that if any of these lists is empty (like `inputs3` in this example), object creation still happens, but corresponding value is not written, and `i3` remains `null`. The problem is that `DefaultIfEmpty()` appears to return `0` instead, therefore `i3` becomes `0` instead of `null`.

I can't seem to find the right way to "tell" `DefaultIfEmpty()` to return `null` when the list is empty. I tried `DefaultIfEmpty((double?)null)`, but compiler doesn't accept such syntax.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`default(double)` is 0, but `default(double?)` is `null`. So you could use `List<double?>` instead of `List<double>`

```
List<double?> inputs1 = new() { 1, 2, 3 };
List<double?> inputs2 = new() { 4, 5 };
List<double?> inputs3 = new() { };
List<double?> inputs4 = new() { 8, 9 };
```

If modifying that brings difficulties, you could always cast to `double?` while processing:

```
List<myClass> myObjects = (
    from double? input1 in inputs1.Select(x => (double?)x).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from double? input2 in inputs2.Select(x => (double?)x).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from double? input3 in inputs3.Select(x => (double?)x).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from double? input4 in inputs4.Select(x => (double?)x).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new myClass()
    {
        i1 = input1,
        i2 = input2,
        i3 = input3,
        i4 = input4
    }
).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, but it does add a bit of complications when these lists are initialized. Is this the only way? Or can that LINQ expression be somehow modified to leave `i3` alone (not assign anything) if corresponding list (`inputs3`) is empty?

Comment: I added one more example where you don't need to change the type while initializing, but can do it in the processing

Comment: Great. Thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I'd use [Cast<T>()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-cast-1(system-collections-ienumerable)) `inputs3.Cast<double?>().DefaultIfEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Cast<double?>` to change the type of the enumerator to a nullable, so the default becomes `null`.

```cs
List<myClass> myObjects = (
    from double? input1 in inputs1.Cast<double?>.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from double? input2 in inputs2.Cast<double?>.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from double? input3 in inputs3.Cast<double?>.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from double? input4 in inputs4.Cast<double?>.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new myClass()
    {
       i1 = input1,
       i2 = input2,
       i3 = input3,
       i4 = input4
    }
).ToList();
```